# LinkedIn Company Feed in API v2?

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn is just changing API and switching from v1 to v2.

API v1 offers endpoints for retrieving data from companies (i.e. information about company, company feed etc.): https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages

It looks that there is no such options in API v2? Am I right?

LinkedIn informed that in order to "manage company pages" one has to participate in Marketing Developer Program (https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program) but even though - new "Organization and Brands API" looks really poor and offers much less information than the old one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations

If anyone know an option to retrieve company feed using LinkedIn API v2?

Comment: Company updates can be retrieved using the /ugcPosts API. `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(url-encoded organization Urn)` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration for reference.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this M. Hryszczyk? Did you need to apply for Marketing Developer Platform to use the URL mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

You are right. Likely linkedin abandoned their API.

**"This API is deprecated. Access is no longer being granted"**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/activity-feed

Comment: Is there any alternative to it? or any new api which linkedin has provided as its replacement?