# LinkedIn company feed/updates in v2 API

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I would like to show a company's feed/updates/post on a website. I am the owner/admin of the LinkedIn page. Most of the related questions are old and uses V1. This similar questions also seems unanswered ([LinkedIn Company Feed in API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012919/linkedin-company-feed-in-api-v2)). LinkedIn support are of no help and they instruct me to ask questions on Stackoverflow.

I created an App on LinkedIn and they assigned default permissions (r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social). But these permissions are of no use to me since I just want to show the company feeds on the website. Neither I want any user to login to LinkedIn nor I want to read the users/visitors email addresses or profile. Already went through a lot of their documentation but there is no clear mentioning of how to do this.

I read that company updates can be retrieved using the /ugcPosts API. GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(url-encoded organization Urn). But in order to do that I need r_organization_social permission. How to get this permission?

Also in this scenario, since I just want to retrieve company posts, I can use 2 legged oauth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context instead of 3 legged oauth. But when I try to generate access token I get error "access_denied: This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://xxxxx.local/&state=fasdfasdfs

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply for the [LinkedIn Marketing Partner Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program). You can do so by adding this product to the app you have created.

Once you have access, you can read the company feed using the following API endpoint:

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:12345&sharesPerOwner=100&count=25

Hope this helps.