# #LinkedIn retrieve posts of a company via API

Tags: linkedin-api

we would like to retrieve postings of a company via API.
We want the postings displayed in our intranet with a jump link to linkedIn.

We checked the documentation but it seams there is no proper endpoint in the API for that use case.

The linkedIn Support told me to ask here if there is a way to do this.

I saw this article, but it's not covering any answer.
But related articles that lead to an explenation that the endpoint for the postings got removed in v2 of the linkedIn API.
So there is no way to receive postings via API?
[LinkedIn Company Feed in API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012919/linkedin-company-feed-in-api-v2?rq=2)
#linkedin